# How to overlay two divs when using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using a parent div which is a flexbox. inside it, i require two child divs, each spanning the complete width of the parent div (width:100%) such that they are on top of each other (overlayed). This way, when you change the width of one child div, it shouldn't re-position the other child div in any way.

for example: i'm trying to create an progress bar of sorts like below:
[image]

for this, i'm using two divs - the outer div (grey background) which renders the progress bar outline, and inner div (green background) which will show the progress. I also require to show the numerical percentage in the middle (81%). the inner div (green bg) width value will wary according to the numerical percentage. The numerical percentage should always be at the center of the OUTER DIV regardless of the progress (inner div width).

Could you please tell me how this can be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you're after, and the code you've tried?  Based on this explanation it sounds like a case of `position: absolute` than flex.

Comment: I've updated the description with an example. tx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For *styling* a basic progress bar, you'd make use of `position: absolute` to overlay items.

You could make use of `flexbox` for positioning purposes, however you'd use less lines of code by just using `position: absolute`, and subsequent rules, on the middle text (e.g. "80%"), enabling both the overlaying need and centering at the same time.

For *controlling* the progress bar (dynamically), you'd use Javascript. You'd build some logic in JS that follows the progress of *something*, and then update the CSS rules of the bar accordingly. There's no way of doing this without JS.

If you just want a dummy progress bar with motion, then you could animate it without JS, by using CSS animation rules.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/LqKGZr)

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;  
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%); 
}

#fill {
  background-color: green;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="text">80%</div>
  <div id="fill">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need flexbox or any complex stuff, you can simply use background for this:

```css
.progress {
  width:200px;
  line-height:50px;
  margin:5px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(green,green) left no-repeat,
    grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  100%
</div>

<div class="progress" style="background-size:50% 100%">
  50%
</div>

<div class="progress" style="background-size:75% 100%">
  75%
</div>
```

You can add more coloration to get closer to the visual you want:

```css
.progress {
  width:200px;
  line-height:50px;
  margin:5px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  background:
    /*light overlay on the half top*/
    linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.3),rgba(255,255,255,0.3)) top/100% 50%,
    /*the two bars*/
    linear-gradient(#539041,#539041) left/5px 100%,
    linear-gradient(#539041,#539041) var(--p,100%) 0/5px 100%,
    /*the progress*/
    linear-gradient(#53e15a,#53e15a) left/var(--p,100%) 100%,
    /*the outer coloration*/
    #bbbbbb;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  100%
</div>

<div class="progress" style="--p:50%">
  50%
</div>

<div class="progress" style="--p:75%">
  75%
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I understood well... Is it something like this that you want to achieve?

HTML

```
<section class="parent">
  <article class="child">
  </article>
  <article class="child">
  </article>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
  height: 60px;
}
```

[Link to codePen](https://codepen.io/bio-tarik/pen/PVrqRj)